# Problem capturing stdout of subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I know that similar questions have been asked before - I have read them and tried the proposed solutions but they didn't work for my specific problem.

I have the need to start a background process using python and continue doing other things while it is running. For context, the process is launched by a pytest fixture and I want to run a test that perform some actions while the process is running; after doing these actions, the test waits for the process to end, assert that it ran without errors and I want to be able to log the stdout of the process mainly for debugging purposes.

After reading through subprocess documentation, I have come to the conclusion that I need to use subprocess.Popen() for my use case. Everything works fine, but when I try to log the stdout of the process using communicate() or readline(), I only get the first line of the stdout, although I am sure that the process runs to completion and generates more lines (I have verified this).

This is the code:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def my_process():
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        args=[
            "pwd" #The actual process is not pwd but it's not relevant for the discussion
        ],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    yield process
    
def test_subprocess(my_process):
    ...
    (perform test actions)
    ...

    assert my_process.wait() == 0
```

Up until this point everything works well. After the assert I have tried to get the stdout by doing

```
stdout, stderr = my_process.communicate()
```

And I have also tried

```
output = my_process.stdout.readline()
```

But it only captures the first line of the output. I am 100% sure there is several more lines of output.

I would like to understand why this happens and how/if I can get the rest of the stdout. Any ideas?

Comment: `pwd` is probably a bad choice of stubs if you need there to be more than one line of output. Please give us a [mre] that _actually reproduces_ your problem when run without changes -- something that's expected to write more output but only emits one line. Not pseudocode; we should be able to copy-and-paste to see the problem ourselves when running it on our own machines. (`args=['printf', '%s\n', 'first line', 'second line']` might not be a bad place to start; but _test that it actually causes the problem_ before editing it into your question).

Comment: To be clear, `readline()` is definitely expected to return only one line at the time, but that's definitely not the case for `communicate()`.